# Is it possible to create vertical text that spans all rows in a CSS Grid?

Tags: css, css-grid

Looking to create a section header for a grid (instead of taking up vertical space by having it above the section), like so:

[image]

It's easy of course to have the first column span the rows with `grid-rows: 1 / span 3` but then if I transform the text and align/justify it, the div doesn't take up the full space of the column, so setting backgrounds/borders doesn't look right.

[See trial pen](https://codepen.io/thekrkn/pen/RxGvGm)

```css
body {
  padding: 1em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.my-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2rem 100px 10rem;
  background-color: #eee
}

.my-grid>* {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.section-title {
  grid-row: 1 / span 5;
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  background-color: papayawhip;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

input {
  border: 2px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-grid">
  <div class="section-title">Address</div>
  <div>Address 1</div>
  <input type="text">
  <div>Address 2</div>
  <input type="text">
  <div>City</div>
  <input type="text">
  <div>State</div>
  <input type="text">
  <div>Zip Code</div>
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

Comment: Solutions to this problem can get pretty complex. For instance, you can remove the vertical header from the grid entirely, then have it positioned next to the grid container. Or, to keep things simple, you may be able to use padding to expand the header size. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vpXbbE

Comment: @Michael_B your technique will not work if the row number is dynamic or if have chance to long text in any cell and line can break more than one line.

Comment: @Hanif, we don't have all the details for this use-case. That's why I posted this idea as a comment, not an answer. Let's see what the OP has to say. This may be a quick, simple and effective solution to his problem. Otherwise, we can consider more complex solutions.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, using `writing-mode`

> The writing-mode CSS property defines whether **lines of text are laid out horizontally or vertically** and the direction in which blocks progress.
>
> <sup>[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode)</sup>

```css
body {
  padding: 1em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.my-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2rem 100px 10rem;
  background-color: #eee
}

.my-grid>* {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.section-title {
  grid-row: 1 / span 5;
  text-align: center;
  writing-mode:vertical-rl; /* vertical text */
  line-height:2rem; /* center in div */
  transform:rotate(180deg); /* spin to orient as required */
  background-color: papayawhip;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

input {
  border: 2px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-grid">
  <div class="section-title">Address</div>
  <div>Address 1</div>
  <input type="text">
  <div>Address 2</div>
  <input type="text">
  <div>City</div>
  <input type="text">
  <div>State</div>
  <input type="text">
  <div>Zip Code</div>
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

Comment: Flex with `justify-content: center` and `align-items: center` also centers the text.

Comment: Yeah but does that fill the background as stated?

Comment: Your `line-height` solution works across browsers (FF, Chrome and Edge). The flex method only works in Chrome and Edge. https://jsfiddle.net/bo4v7fuk/

Comment: While `line-height: 2rem` does fill up the column horizontally, vertically there are still gaps. Ideally, the whole grid column will have a background color, not just under the content.

Comment: @redOctober13 I can't see any vertical gaps...are you sure those aren't borders?

Comment: You're right; it was because I had `align-self: center` on mine.

Comment: Note that a combination of `writing-mode:vertical-rl;` and `transform:rotate(180deg);` will give an unwanted result with languages like Japanese.